# Chrome Extension Badge Color External Website Javascript Change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, badge

Before the manifest change, the extension read a simple .js file written on my site every 5 minutes to tell what color to make the badge. It would change in response to alerts. This manifest has me flummoxed. The request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="alert.js"></script>
```

The background.html reads an external .js file. How?

Comment: What's in `alert.js`? Where are you getting the colour

Comment: Also the background page is literally a page, you can inject the script into `document.head`

Comment: Just a number. The script in the background says if 1 then color if 2 then color. From my under standing, they don't allow it with just a simple insert.

Comment: Why don't you have the actual path to your server in the `src` attribute ? What do you mean by "_it would change in response to alerts_" ? Post more code (manifest, background etc) or express your requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just poll your website and get the colour as a json/xml response? None the less, you should be able to just inject the script as you'd expect - just add it to the web-accessible-resources in manifest:

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": ["http://myserver.com/myscript.js"]
...
```

In background:

```
...

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://myserver.com/myscript.js";
s.addEventListener('load', function (e) {

    /*
    work
    */

}, false);
document.head.appendChild(s);

...
```

Comment: Tried, no luck loading. Would it work better to load a var in the js? For example, in the .js is -> var alert=1;

Comment: Also, is the web_resources... in the "background" or on it's own?

Comment: I believe `web_accessible_resources` is for files **inside** your extension that need to be accessed from external web-pages (e.g. an image injected into a web-page). It won't have any effect here.